# Proving $|\phi (t)|=1$ is sufficient for random variable to have lattice distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

$\phi (t)=E[e^{itX}]$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $X$. $X$ has a lattice distribution if it's support is $\{a+nb,n\in Z, a,b>0\}$, for some $a,b>0$. `I am trying to show that if $X$ has a lattice distribution, then $|\phi(t)|=1$ for some $t\neq 0$`.

My attempt:

$\phi (t)=E[e^{itX}] = E[cos(tX)]+iE[sin(tX)]$

$X\in \{a+nb,n\in Z, a,b>0\}\implies tX\in \{at+nbt,n\in Z, a,b>0\}$

We want $cos(tX)=1$ and $sin(tX)=0$ a.s. $\therefore$ let $bt=2\pi\implies t=\frac{2\pi}{b}$

But $at=a\frac{2\pi}{b}$ need not be $2\pi k$ unless $a=bk$

So am I correct in saying unless $a=bk$, we cannot have a lattice distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of muddled: is the assumption that $|\phi(t)|=1$ or that $X$ has a lattice distribution?

If $|\phi(t)|=1$ for some $t\ne0$, we know that there is a $\theta$ such that $P(Xt \bmod {2\pi} \equiv \theta)=1$.  Because the point $\phi(t)$ is on the boundary of the closed unit disk in the complex plane, and hence an extreme point, and hence the support of the random variable $\exp(itX)$ is a singleton point, call it $\exp(i\theta)$.  Thus, with probability  1 the random variable $X$ takes values in $\{\theta/t +2\pi k /t: k\in \mathbb Z\}.$

Conversely, if $X$ takes values in $\{a+bk: k\in\mathbb Z\}$, we know that $ (X-a)/b$ is integer valued, and hence $\exp(itX)=\exp(ita)$ if $t=2\pi/b$, and hence $|\phi(2\pi/b)|=1$.